# Controls are not showing when using while loop C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

**My code is:**

```
double screenHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
double screenWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
waitingGrid.Height = screenHeight;
waitingGrid.Width = screenWidth;
waitingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
waitingText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
---------
---------
while (!is_approved)
{
     //statements checking whether user got approved and sets is_approved to true
}
```

The problem is when the while loop is **commented** the grid and text are shown. But when while loop is allowed executing the controls are just stuck and does not show up and then the application goes to **Not responding**(by checking task manager).

Why is this so?

Comment: Did you debug the while loop? It looks like the while loop it is taking very long to run, it might be an infinite loop even.

Comment: @Dzyann it is when the other user(the Admin) is offline. He does not get approved.

Comment: You are running a lengthy operation on the user interface thread. So the user interface cannot do what it normally does, and one of the things it normally does is updating the user interface and keeping the application responsive.

Comment: @stijn any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is because ordinarily the main thread of an application sits in a loop that processes user input, etc., but your event handling code, rather than returning immediately so the event loop can handle more input, is entering a `while` loop that won't return until the value of `is_approved` changes.  Since the UI thread is busy in your loop, the only way `is_approved` can change is if you have some background thread that modifies it.  Guessing that you don't, `is_approved` will never change and the `while` loop will never exit, tying up the event loop indefinitely and causing the hang that you see.

Comment: Don't put an infinite `while` loop inside an event handler.

Comment: I need to execute this on a button click. What can i do?

Comment: No, absolutely not.  Assuming that you want is_approved to be changed by some kind of user interaction, figure out what UI event that corresponds to and handle that event by making whatever changes you want to your UI.